# bundle exec を zsh で打たずに済ませる方法

Tags: zsh

zsh を 使っていてカレントのディレクトリに `Gemfile`があれば `bundle exec`を `rake`など特定のコマンドの頭につけるという処理をしたく、[`zsh-bundle-exec`](https://github.com/rhysd/zsh-bundle-exec) をインストールしたのですが正常に入れれてないらしくコマンドの自動付加は行われませんでした。

以下がインストールするために行った処理です。

1. リポジトリを`git clone`
2. `.zshrc`内で環境変数を設定して`zsh-bundle-exec.zsh`を読み込む

   ```
   export BUNDLE_EXEC_GEMFILE_CURRENT_DIR_ONLY=yes
   export BUNDLE_EXEC_COMMANDS='rails rake rspec guard cap'
   source ~/.zsh/zsh-bundle-exec/zsh-bundle-exec.zsh
   ```
3. `. ~/.zshrc` で設定の再読み込み

zshのバージョンは`zsh 5.0.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.0)`を使用しています。

1週間前に Issues に登録させてもらったのですが、反応がまだもらえていません。
https://github.com/rhysd/zsh-bundle-exec/issues/4

このプラグインを使うための正しい設定方法、もしくはその他の方法によるものどちらでも構わないので`bundle exec`の入力を`zsh`で省略する方法は何かありますか？

#### oh-my-zsh に関する追記

kyohsukeさんに教えていただいた `oh-my-zsh`を試してみたのですがうまく動きませんでした。

具体的には

- `alias | grep bi` で `bi=bundle_install`が表示されるためインストールは正常にできている
- プロジェクト内にbinstubされた`bin`フォルダがあると`bin/rake`などが実行される
- `bin`フォルダがない時に `rake db:migrate` すると `bundle exec`が付加されない
- `rake` は `rake=_rake_command`の alias がふられている
- `which _rake_command` は以下の結果

```
_rake_command () {
    if [ -e "bin/rake" ]
    then
        bin/rake $@
    else
        command rake $@
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 5):

自分では試していませんが、こちらでdirenvを使った解決策が紹介されています。

http://mattn.kaoriya.net/software/lang/ruby/20140314032519.htm

あと、完璧な解決策ではありませんが、僕は`~/.zshrc`にエイリアスを設定しています。

```
alias be="bundle exec"
```

こうすれば `be rspec` のような形で実行できます。

ご参考までに。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ただ `direnv`を使う方法ですとプロジェクトごとに毎回設定する必要があるので可能ならば`Gemfile`の有無によってのみ判定するものを探しています。

Answer (score 2):

他の方法になりますが、oh-my-zsh の bundler プラグインを利用するのはどうでしょうか。
bundler プラグインで自動的に bundle exec が挿入されるコマンド一覧は wiki に記載されています。

・[oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh)

もし利用される場合、以下が参考になると思います。

・[Bundlerプラグインについてのwikiページ](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Plugins#bundler) (en)
・[Mac OS X で zsh ＋ oh-my-zsh の環境を作って一通り設定するまで](http://qiita.com/udzura/items/0d08d71d809bfd8c5981)

【追記】

追記された質問内容を調べてみましたところ、oh-my-zshのrailsプラグインに[該当の処理](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/rails/rails.plugin.zsh#L13)が挿入されています。

プラグイン設定を以下のように bundler のみにするとどうでしょうか。
`plugins=( bundler )`

Comment: ありがとうございます。oh-my-zshをインストールして bundler plugin を有効にしたのですが自動補完が行われていないようです…。 `be rake db:migrate` などの短縮コマンドが自分自身では設定してないのに有効になっているので plugin の読み込みは正常に行われていると思うのですが。

Comment: bundle exec が付加できる場合に自動でつけて処理をする形になるので、付与される前のコマンドが履歴に残りますね・・・付与した後のコマンドを履歴に残す方法はわからないです、すいません。

Comment: いえ、`bundle exec`の付与自体がされないんです。`rake db:migrate` ではバージョン差異のエラーが出て、`be rake db:migrate` では正常にエラーなく実行されます。

Comment: まず `alias bi="bundle install"` 等を設定していない状態で `alias | grep bi` をしてみるとどのように表示されますでしょうか？ こちらが `bi=bundle_install` となっていれば bundler プラグインが読み込まれています。 それでも動かない場合、おそらく binstubs の機能にひっかかっています。この機能は現在のディレクトリに `bin` ディレクトリが存在し、その中に同名の実行スクリプトがある場合そちらを優先して呼びます。 この時は bundle exec が付与されませんので、bi エイリアスを利用するしかありません。 `rake db:migrate` ということは恐らく `rails new` で生成したディレクトリだと思われますが、その中に `bin` ディレクトリが存在していると思います。 この場合は手で bi を入力するしかないので oh-my-zsh では解決策となりません。 すいません。

Comment: `alias | grep bi` で `bi=bundle_install`の記述は確認できました。またbinstubの`bin`ディレクトリがあるときはそちらが呼ばれることも確認できています。確認のために`bin`ディレクトリを別の場所に移動して試してみましたが`bundle exec`の補完がされない状態です。時間がある時にoh-my-zshのソースを追って見ることにします。ありがとうございました。

Comment: いま試してみましたが、こちらでは `mv bin _bin` とすることで `bundle exec` が正しく付与されました。 あと可能性があるとすれば別の場所で `alias rake="..."`されているくらいしか思いつかないですね………お力になれなくてすいません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。質問に情報を追加しておきます。